# Expose a Fortran variable to C

Tags: binding, fortran

I learned how to use C global variables in Fortran code, as given in the example below. But how to do it in a reverse direction, i.e., define (and initialize) a variable in Fortran and make it accessible to C?

```
/* C global variables */

int c_extern;
long myVariable;

!Fortran binding code
MODULE LINK_TO_C_VARS
    USE ISO_C_BINDING
    !Implicit label binding
    !Bind variable C_EXTERN to c_extern
    INTEGER(C_INT), BIND(C) :: C_EXTERN

    !Explicit label binding
    !Bind C2 to myVariable
    INTEGER(C_LONG) :: C2
    BIND(C, NAME='myVariable') :: C2
END MODULE LINK_TO_C_VARS
```

Comment: A global variable shared between Fortran and C can be modified with code of either language.  The resulting change will show to the variable visible to the other language.  It works in both directions.  If you have a specific problem, please show all relevant code.

Comment: Your code works OK, just compile it `gcc -shared vars.c mod.f90 -o lib.so`  and the library contains those variables.

Comment: Will this statement "INTEGER(C_INT), BIND(C) :: C_EXTERN" allocate the variable in the generated .o object? I am confused who does the memory allocation, C or Fortran.

Comment: It doesn't matter.   With the ISO_C_BINDING, Fortran "knows" that the Fortran variable is the same as the C variable.  There is only one storage reserved by the executable.  The compatible Fortran/C compiler pair takes care of it.

Comment: A slight correction to MSB's last - it is BIND(C) that tells Fortran the variable is to be interoperable with C. The use of ISO_C_BINDING, on its own, has nothing to do with this.

Comment: You should put the stuff you added to your question into an answer and accept it, that's OK to do and will help others searching for already answered questions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow-up:

Thanks to M.S.B.

I did some experiments. I put the C code in vars.c, the Fortran code in      mod.f90.

```
gcc -c vars.c
nm vars.o
0000000000000004 C c_extern
0000000000000008 C myVariable

gfortran -c mod.f90
nm mod.o
0000000000000004 C c_extern
0000000000000008 C myVariable
```

'man nm' says: "C"  --  The symbol is common.  Common symbols are uninitialized data.  When linking, multiple common symbols may appear with the same name.  If the symbol is defined anywhere, the common symbols are treated as undefined references.

Then, I changed variables in vars.c to extern

```
<<vars-ext.c>>
extern int c_extern;
extern long myVariable;
```

gcc -c vars-ext.c and nm vars-ext.o

```
U c_extern
U myVariable
```

gfortran can successfully link mod.o with vars.o or vars-ext.o. It looks that the magic lies in the "C" kind symbols.